# Implications of making Activity Fields (Subject, Duration, Location, Details) required

Tags: activities

I've been asked to make the standard activity fields
Subject, Duration, Location, Activity Details
required. I can see how to do this from this ticket.

[Requiring "Assigned" and "Target" contacts when recording Activity](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3827/requiring-assigned-and-target-contacts-when-recording-activity)

My question is what would be the implications of doing this? Are any of these fields also used by events, mailings or contributions modules to record interactions, so would setting them to mandatory cause problems with these activity types?

Thought I'd ask before taking a suck it and see approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best approach would be to use `hook_civicrm_validateForm` to make those fields required from the Activity screen only: http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/hook_civicrm_validateForm